# Need to compare to tables and show one rows data in place of other

Tags: php, mysql

Ok lets say it looks like this in table users_chars i have

```
pos_zone
255
```

in table two

```
zone_id | name
 255    | This_Area
```

how would i go about comparing them and showing the name row instead of the id

Comment: [`JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t.name
from users_chars uc
inner join table_two t on uc.pos_zone = t.zone_id
```

What this means:

`select t.name` tells the database which column you want to show/retrieve data for

`from users_chars uc` get data from the users_chars table and give it an alias of "uc" (if the ID doesn't exist in UC, you won't be able to get the name from table_two)

`inner join table_two t on uc.pos_zone = t.zone_id` pos_zone column from the users_chars table  contains the same data as zone_id in table_two, so link those 2 together (typically a foreign key relationship, but it doesn't have to be). Also give table_two an alias of "t"

Comment: So would this be right sorry new to sql     $poszone=mysql_query("SELECT t.name
from users_chars uc
inner join zone_settings t on uc.pos_zone = t.zoneid");
   echo "<td>" . $poszone . "</td>";

Comment: SQL query is fine, but you'll have to loop through your result set (mysql_fetch_array)

Answer (score 1):

```
select t.name
from users_chars c
inner join table_two t on c.pos_zone = t.zone_id
where c.pos_zone = 255
```