# Show one table's row info in place of other using data from two tables

Tags: php, mysql

Ok lets say it looks like this in table users_chars i have

```
pos_zone
255
```

in table two

```
zone_id | name
 255    | This_Area
```

how would i go about comparing them and showing the name row instead of the id

Ok using the method @missdefying posted I came up with this is this ok?

```
  ////Zone id to name
        $zoneid=myQ(myF("SELECT t.zoneid
FROM users_chars c
INNER JOIN zone_settings t ON c.pos_zone = t.zoneid"));

        $result=mysql_query("SELECT t.name
FROM users_chars uc
INNER JOIN zone_settings t ON uc.pos_zone = t.zoneid");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $zonename = "";
if (($row['pos_zone'] == $zoneid)) {
$zonename = "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";}
echo "<td>" . $zonename ."</td>";}
```

@missdefying Thank you

Comment: what is your question exactly? If you are getting the results that you want then it must be working right ?

Comment: Are you storing like the id's in one table and the name's in another and just want to query with the id and have the zone name return?  I would assume that you would just do `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE \`zone_id\`=255` and then just use `echo $row['name']` in your `while` statement.

Comment: you only need the second query and no if, also is the last line a typo? you're wrapping a <td> inside another <td>

Comment: @Maximus2012 it is giving the result however it only works partially idk why but it will not do it for some users.

Comment: @evan.stoddard thanks like I siad new to this so taking some time lol

Comment: @koala_dev Wow can't believe I did not see that thanks

Comment: Possible(!) duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17998851/need-to-compare-to-tables-and-show-one-rows-data-in-place-of-other